# NodeJS library for testing incoming HTTP requests

Tags: node.js, sinon, chai

I'm looking for a library(-ies) that would help me accomplish this:

- Start an HTTP server on a specified port (like you would in Express)
- Check that during a specified timeout N requests have hit this server
- Check their format

There are numerous libraries to check that some certain server *responds* correctly to the requests you send: `chaijs` for example. Then there are libraries to spy on the functions *in your own code* and check for the amount of time they're called and their parameters, e.g. `sinon`. But it won't allow you to create a server that would listen to incoming requests (like `express` does).

To give more context. I have a meta-component consisting of 2 micro-services and an SQS queue (input-queue-output). I want to run an integration test that

1. sends the request to the input
2. waits for a pre-defined timeout
3. receives the incoming request from the output
4. verifies certain assertions

Now, it's easy to just send a request. Or to just listen to a request. But how exactly do I do both in the same test suite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work :

1. Start an `express` server `before` the test, configure it to call a `mock` on each request it receives
2. During the test send the requests, and at the end `expect` your `mock` [to have been called n times](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#tohavebeencalledtimesnumber)
3. `after` the test stop your server

Comment: Thanks! This pretty much addresses all my points. One thing I'm not sure is timeout: how do I factor timeout into that algorithm? Ideally I would need to end the test either when all the expected requests came in or when the timeout expired, whichever comes first.

Comment: In jest, tests takes the timeout as the 3rd param : https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/api.html#testname-fn-timeout

Comment: If your test ends too early, the timeout will not help, you may need to add a "sleep" instead.